# porque me sale un scroll a horizontal?

Tags: html, css

soy bastante nuevo en esto del desarrollo web, quiero saber porque luego de hacer mi html y css recargo mi pagina y me sale un scroll horizontal, todo se ve mas grande y al lado derecho un espaciado blanco, a la vista de 80% de google se logra ver bien, pero al 100% no, que debo hacer? de hecho vi el uso de overflow-x hidden, lo use y mejoro un poco pero sigue el error... he hecho muchas cosas que veo en internet pero sigue sin solucion. Acepto correciones del codigo y demas, soy novato, graciasssss.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html{

    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

body{

}

.container__header{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: #3090F6;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}
.menu{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 26px;
    right: 418px;
    left: 1008px;
    display: flex;
    top: 27px;
}

.menu nav ul{
    display: flex;
}

.menu nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 110px;
} 

.menu nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 130%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
}

/*boton*/

.header__contacto{
    position: relative;
    width: 175px;
    height: 53px;
    right: 143px;
    left: 1602px;
}

.btn__header-register{
    position: absolute;
    width: 175px;
    height: 53px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    color:#3090F6;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.grafismo5{
    background-image: url(/Portafolio\ Daniel/.grafismo5);
    right: 1462.11px;
}

.text__information-cover{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1248px;
    height: 156px;
    left: 336px;
    top: 413px;
}

.imgs{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    right: 582px;
}

.img__Daniel__cover{
    position: absolute;
    left: 280px;
    top: 1046px;
    width: 372px;
    height: 428px;
}

.img__groups__cover{
    position: absolute;
    width: 372px;
    height: 538px;
    left: 1234px;
    top: 1022px;
}

.daniel-copy{
    position: absolute;
    left: 280px;
    top: 1500px;
    height: 78px;
    width: 372px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 130%;
    color: #222222;
}

.product-designer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 266px;
    height: 39px;
    left: 280px;
    top: 1572px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 130%;
    color: #2782ED;
}

.ceo-workpoint{
    position: absolute;
    width: 157px;
    height: 26px;
    left: 280px;
    top: 1611px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 130%;
    color: #222222; 
}

.cuatro-años{
    position: absolute;
    width: 788px;
    height: 49px;
    left: 280px;
    top: 1663px;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;
}

.director-general{
    position: absolute;
    width: 972px;
    height: 49px;
    left: 280px;
    top: 1712px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;
    color: #222222;
}

.actualmente-lidero{
    position: absolute;
    width: 880px;
    height: 49px;
    left: 280px;
    top: 1761px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;
    color: #222222; 
}

.grafismo2{
    background-image: url(/Portafolio\ Daniel/.grafismo2);
    position: absolute;
    left: 1773px;
    top: 1686px;
}

.logo-workpoint{
    position: absolute;
    width: 482px;
    height: 296.83px;
    left: 719px;
    top: 2254px;
}

.agencia-data{
    position: absolute;
    left: 501px;
    top: 2671px;
}

.copy-agencia{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1625px;
    height: 106px;
    left: 148px;
    top: 2774px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222222;
}

.no-buttons-1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 535px;
    top: 2965px;
}

.no-buttons-2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 985px;
    top: 2967px; 
}

.grafismo3{
    background-image: url(/Portafolio\ Daniel/.grafismo3);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 2889px;
}

.sub-titulo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 435px;
    height: 78px;
    left: 199px;
    top: 3584px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 130%;
    color: #FF4B4B;
}

.primer-parrafo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 853px;
    height: 157px;
    left: 199px;
    top: 3676px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;
    color: #222222;
}

.segundo-parrafo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 916px;
    height: 151px;
    left: 199px;
    top: 3847px;   
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;
    color: #222222;
}
.resorte__third-cover{
    position: absolute;
    left: 1351px;
    top: 3783px;
}

.hace-que{
    position: absolute;
    width: 494px;
    height: 78px;
    left: 199px;
    top: 4052px;  
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 130%;
    color: #222222;
}

.no-entiendan{
    position: absolute;
    width: 853px;
    height: 93px;
    left: 199px;
    top: 4144px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;
    color: #222222;
}

.terminan-perdiendo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 199px;
    top: 4260px;
}

.remoto{
    position: absolute;
    width: 764px;
    height: 78px;
    left: 569px;
    top: 4821px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222222;
    display: flex;
}
.remoto-color{
    color: #2782ED;
}

.oportunidades-copy{
    position: absolute;
    width: 835px;
    height: 103px;
    left: 534px;
    top: 4912px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;   
    text-align: center; 
    color: #222222;
}

.oficina__fourth-cover{
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    top: 5133px;
}

.playa__fourth-cover{
    position: absolute;
    left: 1029px;
    top: 5145px;
}

.viajes-playa{
    position: absolute;
    width: 392px;
    height: 49px;
    left: 338px;
    top: 5586px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222222;
}

.computador-cerrado{
    position: absolute;
    width: 338px;
    height: 49px;
    left: 1200px;
    top: 5586px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%; 
    text-align: center;
    color: #222222;
}

.data-importante{
    position: absolute;
    width: 735px;
    height: 78px;
    left: 593px;
    top: 6070px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222222;
}

.data-blue{
    color: #2782ED;
}

.important-blue{
    color: #2782ED;
}

.ultimo-copy{
    position: absolute;
    width: 896px;
    height: 103px;
    left: 512px;
    top: 6180px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 190%;   
    text-align: center;
    color: #222222;
}

.rare-form{
    position: absolute;
    left: 738px;
    top: 6341px;
}

.blue-form{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 6784px;
    background: #3090F6;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Daniel Arias</title>

    <link href="/Portafolio Daniel/CODE/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Poppins:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>

        <div class="container__header">
            <div class="menu">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="inicio">inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="servicios">Servicios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="comunidad">Comunidad</a></li> 
                    </ul> 
                </nav>
            </div> 

            <div class="header__contacto">
                <input type="button" class="btn__header-register" value="Contacto">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="ilustrations">
            <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Grafismo 5.png" class="grafismo5">
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="text__information-cover"> 
            <div>
                <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Cómo hacer crecer tu marca o producto a través del marketing digital.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cover">
            <div class="media__cover">
                <div class="imgs">
                    <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Daniel.png" class="img__Daniel__cover">
                    <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Group 2271.png" class="img__groups__cover">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2 class="daniel-copy">Daniel Arias</h2><br>
                    <p class="product-designer">Product Designer</p><br>
                    <p class="ceo-workpoint">CEO-Workpoint</p><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="cuatro-años">4 Años de experiencia en estrategia y diseño de procesos</li>
                        <li class="director-general">Director General y Co-Fundador de 2 organizaciones sin ánimo de lucro</li>
                        <li class="actualmente-lidero">Actualmente lidero 2 Startups que están creciendo rápidamente</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ilustrations">
            <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Grafismo 2.png" class="grafismo2">
        </div>
        <div class="second-cover">
            <div class="container__media-cover2">
                <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Group 2232.png" class="logo-workpoint">
            </div>
            <div class="text__workpoint-second-cover">
                <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Agencia de DATA y Marketing.png" class="agencia-data"><br>
                <p class="copy-agencia">Workpoint, es una startup dedicada a la recolección de data generada por los usuarios/clientes de las distintas empresas en Colombia, con el fin de analizarla para posteriormente generar estrategias de marketing que beneficien a las empresas. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="no-buttons__second-cover">
            <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Group 2272.png" class="no-buttons-1">
            <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Group 2273.png" class="no-buttons-2">
        </div>
        <div class="ilustrations">
                <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Grafismo 3.png" class="grafismo3">
        </div>
        <div class="third-cover">
            <div class="text-information__third-cover">
                <div class="h4">
                    <h4 class="sub-titulo">Problemática</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="copy__third-cover">
                    <p class="primer-parrafo">Colombia hace parte de los paises que de manera más lenta transforma su industria y la adapta al los cambios tecnologicos, siempre espera a ver en que innova Estados Unidos o China.
                    </p><br>
                    <p class="segundo-parrafo">Muchos empresarios corren el pánico de que sus empresas quiebren debido a que no han sabido como adaptarse a la tecnología, y no es culpa de ellos, vienen de una epoca diferente a la actual.</p> 
                    <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Group 2172.png" class="resorte__third-cover">
                </div>
                <div class="second-copy__third-cover">
                    <h5 class="hace-que">Esto hace que...</h5>
                    <p class="no-entiendan">No entiendan a sus usuarios/clientes, por lo que no saben como ofrecer sus productos o servicios de una manera adecuada.</p>
                    <div class="text-deforme__third-cover">
                        <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Terminan perdiendo clientes potenciales..png" class="terminan-perdiendo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fourth/cover">
            <div class="text-information__fourth-cover">
                <h5 class="remoto">¿Qué es <span class="remoto-color">Trabajo remoto</span>?</h5>
                <p class="oportunidades-copy">Dá más oportunidades de flexibilidad a los empleados, además te permite disminuir los costos fijos como arriendo y servicios.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="media-fourth-cover">
                <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Art-247-oficina-gente-trabajando-1 1.png" class="oficina__fourth-cover">
                <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/portatil-playa-teletrabajador 1.png" class="playa__fourth-cover">
            </div>
            <div class="copy-imgs">
                <p class="viajes-playa">A 10 horas de viaje de la playa</p>
                <p class="computador-cerrado">Solo cierra el computador</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="text-information_footer">
                <h6 class="data-importante">La <span class="data-blue">DATA</span> es <span class="important-blue">IMPORTANTE</span></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="copy__footer">
                <p class="ultimo-copy">Los datos de las personas (demográficos, psicográficos, comsumo) son la llave de la entrada al mundo digital.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="iustration">
                <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Group 2239.png" class="rare-form">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container__blue-form">
            <img src="/Portafolio Daniel/resources/imgs/Rectangle 2076.png" class="blue-form">
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en que le estas asignando un valor al menu lo que fuerza a desplaza el tamaño del navegador. Remplaza solo esto y listo!

```
.container__header{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: #3090F6;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}
.menu{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 26px;
    right: 418px;
    left: 1008px;
    display: flex;
    top: 27px;
}
```

Comment: Fíjate que el ancho del menú paso a ser de 100vw. Se veía un poco enredado el código, si te genera otro inconveniente escribime. Al probarlo comprobé que funciona pero no lo puedo ver al 100% el resto ya que no tengo las imágenes. Saludo!

Comment: Manito arriba si te sirvio! Me ayuda para mejorar mi reputación y poder seguir respondiendo mas preguntas y ayudar al resto!

Comment: Dale, de verdad gracias por tu respuesta, claro que si, gracias por la ayuda.